# Obtener informacion de una Ventana Tkinter de Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy empezando programacion de GUI en Python y he logrado crear unas ventanas mediante Tkinter y Programacion Orientada a Objeto (POO). Sin embargo, requiero que muchas de las ventanas se pueda enviar informacion y asi mismo recibir la informacion actualizada del usuario pero mediante POO no encuentro la forma de recibir/guardar la informacion que se ingresa en la ventana luego de finalizar su ejecución. ¿ Es esto posible mediante POO o debo construir ventanas con funciones ?.
Mi idea mediante funciones seria pasar una copia de un objeto que llene los datos a mostrar en la ventana y devolver ese mismo objeto el cual va guardando/actualizando sus datos durante la ejecucion de la ventana. Solo si el usuario ha cerrado la ventana mediante el boton "Guardar" se regresa la copia del objeto junto con una variable booliana que desde fuera de la ejecucion del programa se pueda preguntar; si la variable booliana es True entonces asignar los datos del objeto copia al objeto original, sino, entonces mantener lo datos del objeto original.

Si alguien tiene una mejor forma o mas experiencia agradezco mucho.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], leas [ask] y agregues un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: @AndresGardiol yo creo que el OP si intentó algo, solo que busca una mejor forma.

Answer (score 0):

#### Lo que yo suelo hacer: uso de modulos

Yo, cuando me choco con el tema de compartir datos globalmente a través de tooodo el programa, me gusta usar un módulo.

En Python, cuando importamos un modulo, su código solo se ejecuta una vez. Intentar importar nuevamente el modulo, resultará en que se devuelva el objeto modulo que está en cache.

Podemos usar esto a nuestro favor para, por ejemplo, compartir una conexión sql a todos los programas sin necesidad de pasar los datos como argumento ni matarnos con crear muchas referencias en cada ventana.

###### Ejemplo

**modulo.py**

```
# inicializamos valor con un default
valor = "hola"
```

**ventanas.py**

```
import modulo
import ventanas2
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        e = tk.Entry()
        e.insert(0, modulo.valor)
        e.bind("<Return>", self.update_value)
        e.pack()

    def update_value(self, event):
        modulo.valor = event.widget.get()
        ventanas2.Info(self)

window = Window()
window.mainloop()
```

**ventanas2.py**

```
import modulo
import tkinter as tk

class Info(tk.Toplevel)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tk.Label(self, text=modulo.valor).pack()
```

**Nota** Si bien, los valores en el modulo pueden actualizarse desde cualquier lado, la ventana no será actualizada en tiempo real con los nuevos valores automaticamente. Para que eso pase, tendrás que hacer un sistema que vaya actualizando los widgets asociados según el valor cambie. Pero por lo que leí, ese no es tu objetivo. Así que no me centraré en eso.